# Syntax error in update generated by codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, sql-update, syntax-error

I am using codeigniter and with this there is a sql query. I know where is the problem but don't know to write the proper query for it.
I got error like this,

```
UPDATE `fx_tasks` 
SET `timer_status` = 'On', `start_time` = 1444629730, `timer_started_by` = '46' 
WHERE `t_id` = '3438' 
ORDER BY `timer_status=On` DESC
```

My codeingiter query is like,

```
$this->db->set('timer_status', $action);
$this->db->set('start_time', time());
$this->db->set('timer_started_by', $this -> user);
$this->db->order_by("timer_status=On","DESC");
$this->db->where('t_id',$task)->update($this->tasks_table);
```

What is the proper query in codeigniter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `update` statement doesn't have an `order by` clause. Remove it from your codeigniter code:

```
$this->db->set('timer_status', $action);
$this->db->set('start_time', time());
$this->db->set('timer_started_by', $this -> user);
$this->db->where('t_id',$task)->update($this->tasks_table);
// order by removed
```

And you should get a valid update statement:

```
UPDATE `fx_tasks` 
SET    `timer_status` = 'On',
       `start_time` = 1444629730,
       `timer_started_by` = '46'
WHERE  `t_id` = '3438'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Codeigniter Update function](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)

```
date_default_timezone_set('asia/kolkata')
$user = $this->user;
$data = array(
       'timer_status' => $action,
       'start_time' => date('H:i:s'),
       'timer_started_by' => $user
    );

$this->db->where('t_id', $task);
$this->db->update('fx_tasks', $data);
```

> `date('H:i:s')` return current time with provide time zone. If you need to print timestamp  use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`